# partly no connection over sfp+

Tags: fiber, sfp

I have a really weird problem with a fiber connection.

I have 2x2 fibers OM4 G50/125 between two rooms, room A & B (fiber length approximately 20m).

I have two switches, a Huawei CE6810 and a HP 2530-48G-2sfp+ (each has a sfp+ module).

1) When I have the switches side by side, connected via fiber it works.

2) When I have one switch in room A, and the other in room B connected via fiber it does not work

```
HUAWEI -- A ---------- B -- HP
```

A = room A, B = Room B, - = fiber connection

3) When I connect one of the fiber pairs between the rooms to the other one (so both ends in Room A) and connect both switches it works.

```
HUAWEI -- A ---------- B 
                       |
     HP-- A ---------- B
```

This utilizes the same fiber connection, the total length is just double. 
I have no idea how to even start looking for the problem.

thanks
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel so stupid, of course I should have just checked the polarity of the cable (is it called polarity in english?)

2 Patch Cables --> not patched
3 Patch Cables --> patched again.